# Unable to boot Ubuntu from USB and other external media

Tags: installation

I replaced my laptop's hard drive a few months back and promptly installed 12.04 on it. However, since there were still some files for which I needed Windows 7, I installed Windows 7 afterwards, removing my access to Ubuntu and the dual-boot setup which I had intended to build.

I only realized a couple weeks *afterwards* that I had the installation order mixed up, but since I was in the middle of classes, and most of what I'm doing now doesn't require Ubuntu/*nix, I let it slide.

Now that I'm back to doing my own projects, I need Ubuntu again, and have tried (and repeatedly) failed to get my computer to boot into the Ubuntu Desktop installer for 12.10. I've tried:

1. Booting from USB (with the help of Universal USB installer).
2. Booting from DVD.
3. Booting from eSATA.
4. Booting from Ethernet/Network.

No matter how I try though, even after editing the BIOS load order to load the hard drive last, it still refuses to boot it from any of these sources.

**TL;DR**
I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) Desktop on my computer, then Windows 7, which removed my ability to access Ubuntu. Am now trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit) Desktop, but computer does not boot from any external sources.

Is there a workaround, or will I just have to reformat my hard drive and start from scratch again?

Specs:
Computer: [Toshiba L655-S5075](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=SB&os=&category=&moid=2681578&rpn=PSK2GU&modelFilter=&selCategory=2756709&selFamily=1073768663)
Hard Drive: [Seagate Momentus 7200 750 GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MME0N0)
CPU: Intel Core i3 2.26 GHz (64-Bit)
RAM: 4 GB DDR3

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to pop [rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) on a usb thumb drive and use its wizard to install the grub again. Good luck.